# MySQL и хоролог

Tags: mysql, кэширование

Есть поле, которое выгружается нам из Cache, содержащее хоролог, типа 63677,86100 или 63677,60.
Разумеется, работать с этим не удобно. Есть ли варианты перевода этого самого хоролога в юникстайм, например, без лишних извращений?

Держу в уме вариант с разбиением хоролог по запятой и дальнейшей работой с двумя этими частями, но это тот еще мазохизм.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Боюсь, без извращений никак.
могу только предложить пару функций для облегчения процесса

```
from_days(672411+63677) -- получаем дату
sec_to_time(86100) -- получаем время
```

ну и `substring_index` чтобы части добывать

```
concat(
    from_days(672411 + substring_index(horolog,',',1)),
    ' ',
    sec_to_time(substring_index(horolog,',',-1))
)
```

если хотим юникстайм, то добавить `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.

Comment: Да, примерно об этом я и писал. Печально, что приходится так извращаться.